# Java: Searching an unsorted integer array for the first occurrence of a user inputted integer

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, java.util.scanner

I've noticed two problem and would really appreciate the help!

1. With (what I believe) to be with how the methods "arrayIndex" and "position" are interacting with each other. I say this because when I enter the same exact numbers for both of the fields they return the same exact values even though they are supposed to handle completely different tasks.
2. With my "position" method which is supposed to return the location of the searched values first occurrence in the array it seems to return incorrect values and after inspecting it I still can not figure out why. If the user searches for a values position that doesn't exist it's supposed to return a "-1".

My Entire Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog9ArrayMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Daily high temperatures for Portland Maine Jan 1 - Dec 31 2015
        int[] tmax = {32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 
                      29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36, 31, 38, 35, 32, 37, 20, 17, 26, 
                      30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 
                      20, 17, 16, 19, 21, 21, 32, 33, 19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 
                      21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 
                      41, 39, 38, 36, 45, 44, 28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 
                      49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 
                      35, 43, 54, 68, 66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 
                      53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 
                      84, 58, 59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 
                      69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61, 
                      60, 58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 
                      72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69, 75, 68, 
                      78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 
                      76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67, 67, 77, 83, 88, 
                      86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 
                      77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75, 73, 78, 70, 79, 75, 80, 
                      79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 
                      78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83, 85, 82, 83, 75, 72, 69, 65, 74, 
                      74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 
                      63, 59, 56, 68, 70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57, 46, 48, 66, 58, 
                      65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 
                      68, 69, 65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60, 46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 
                      53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44, 
                      45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53, 48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 
                      50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34, 23, 28, 
                      44};

        int max = arrayMax(tmax);
        int min = arrayMin(tmax);
        double average = arrayAverage(tmax);
        int count = arrayIndex(tmax);
        int i = arrayIndex(tmax);
        System.out.println("Maximum value is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum value is: " + min);
        System.out.println("Average value is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The number of values above the specified value is: " + count);
        System.out.println("The first occurence of the searched value is: " + i);
    }

    // Returns the maximum value in the array
    public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
        int max = a[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];

        return max; 
    }
    // Returns the minimum value in the array
    public static int arrayMin (int[] a) {
        int min = a[0];    

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (a[i] < min)
                    min = a[i];
            return min;
    }
    // Returns the average value in the array
    public static double arrayAverage(int[] a) {  
        int sum = 0; // Why does it double the decimal value with "int sum = a[0]"?
        double average;

            for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
                sum = sum + a[i];
            }
            average = (double)sum/a.length;
            return average;
    }
    // Returns the number of values greater than the user's indexed values
    public static int arrayIndex(int[] a) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
        int userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); 

        int count = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if(a[i] > userSearch) {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            return count;
    }
    public static int position(int [ ] a, int match) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
        int userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          {
               if ( a[i] == userSearch )
                     return i;
          }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `position` method at all.

Comment: @4castle Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: Your code never calls the `position` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your main method, when you want to get `i` to be the count, you actually get `arrayIndex()` instead of `position()`.
Just change `int i = arrayIndex(tmax);` to `int i = position(tmax);` and get rid of the `int match()` as an argument to `position()`

Comment: @Aramza Arrays are 0-indexed, so the output you are seeing is correct. If you want the array to be 1-indexed, just add 1 to the index you return.

Comment: Arrays start at 0 instead of 1, because of how they work. Just add 1 to the return value of position()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem. Your were calling arrayIndex method twice instead of calling position method. I rectified your code. Now it works fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Prog9ArrayMethods {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Daily high temperatures for Portland Maine Jan 1 - Dec 31 2015
    int[] tmax = {32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 
                  29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36, 31, 38, 35, 32, 37, 20, 17, 26, 
                  30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 
                  20, 17, 16, 19, 21, 21, 32, 33, 19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 
                  21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 
                  41, 39, 38, 36, 45, 44, 28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 
                  49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 
                  35, 43, 54, 68, 66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 
                  53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 
                  84, 58, 59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 
                  69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61, 
                  60, 58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 
                  72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69, 75, 68, 
                  78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 
                  76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67, 67, 77, 83, 88, 
                  86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 
                  77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75, 73, 78, 70, 79, 75, 80, 
                  79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 
                  78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83, 85, 82, 83, 75, 72, 69, 65, 74, 
                  74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 
                  63, 59, 56, 68, 70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57, 46, 48, 66, 58, 
                  65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 
                  68, 69, 65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60, 46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 
                  53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44, 
                  45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53, 48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 
                  50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34, 23, 28, 
                  44};

    int max = arrayMax(tmax);
    int min = arrayMin(tmax);
    double average = arrayAverage(tmax);
    int count = arrayIndex(tmax);
    int i = position(tmax);
    System.out.println("Maximum value is: " + max);
    System.out.println("Minimum value is: " + min);
    System.out.println("Average value is: " + average);
    System.out.println("The number of values above the specified value is: " + count);
    System.out.println("The first occurence of the searched value is: " + i);
}

// Returns the maximum value in the array
public static int arrayMax(int[] a) {
    int max = a[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];

    return max; 
}
// Returns the minimum value in the array
public static int arrayMin (int[] a) {
    int min = a[0];    

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] < min)
                min = a[i];
        return min;
}
// Returns the average value in the array
public static double arrayAverage(int[] a) {  
    int sum = 0; // Why does it double the decimal value with "int sum = a[0]"?
    double average;

        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        average = (double)sum/a.length;
        return average;
}
// Returns the number of values greater than the user's indexed values
public static int arrayIndex(int[] a) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter a value to search for arrayIndex: ");
    int userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); 

    int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] > userSearch) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
}
public static int position(int [ ] a) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter a value to search: ");
    int userSearch = user_input.nextInt(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      {
           if ( a[i] == userSearch )
                 return i;
      }
     return -1;
}
```

}